# Does chanting Ram's name during Brahma Muhurat or the month of Kartika affect the quality/quantity of the japa?

Tags: rama, japa

Does chanting Ram's name during the Brahma Muhurat give 10x results than the normal japa? Is mansik japa 1 crorex more powerful than Vaikhari japa?

Does chanting Ram's name during the month of Kartika give 1000x results than in a normal month?